# UISegmentedControl to determine contents of Dynamic UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm working on an iOS storyboard app with a `UITableView` and dynamic cells. I want a segmented control to determine which type of cell populates the `tableView` contents.

Here is The viewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[_reelsOrAllSegmentedControl addTarget:self
                                action:@selector(segmentedControlTouched)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier0 = @"cellType1";
NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"cellType2";
long row = [indexPath row];
if([_segmentedControl isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:0])
{
    CellType1 *cell = [tableView
                                        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier0
                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *folderArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[UserSession sharedSession] userFolders]];
    [[cell titleTextView]  setText:(NSString*)folderArray[row][@"title"]];
else if([_segmentedControl isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:1]){
    CellType2 *cell = [tableView
                                  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1
                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *postArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[UserSession sharedSession] userPosts]];
    cell.captionTextView.text = postArray[row][@"caption"];
    return cell;
}

-(void)segmentedControlTouched
{
    NSLog(@"touch");
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Every time I switch the segmented control, the first block of the `if` is run. Shouldn't the second one be run when the table is refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off creating two separate classes implementing `UITableViewDataSource`, and setting the table view's `dataSource` appropriately when the user changes the selected segment.

But anyway, you can get your code working by looking at the control's `selectedSegmentIndex` property:

```
if(_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    CellType1 *cell = [tableView
    ... etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, Why would I be better off using dataSource?

Comment: Because otherwise you will end up with `if` statements all over the place.